# How to prove $f: N \to \{0,1\}$ where not exist i where $f(i)=f(i+1)=1$ are uncountable using cantor's diagonal?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

I know how to prove that $f: N\to \{ 0,1 \}$ are uncountable but in this case
I have a problem where that might be:

$f_1: 000000000000...$
$f_2: 001000000000...$
$f_3: 000100000000...$

If I take the opposite of the diagonal it goes: $111$ and that isn't a function I'm looking for.

I think it's very interesting quesion.

Thanks!

Comment: Sure you want to use Cantor's diagonal argument?

Comment: yes I do, that's what I need on the question

Comment: If you are **asked to**, fine, otherwise there are other, more direct, ways.

Comment: Note that $n$ usually denotes a *finite set*, and your notation implies that $f$ is a function from a finite set into $\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call a function $f$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0,1\}$ **good** if there is no integer $i$ such that $f(i)=f(i+1)=1$.  Informally, such a function is a sequence with no two consecutive $1$'s.

We show that the set of good functions is uncountable.

Suppose to the contrary that the set of good functions is countable. Let  $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4, \dots$ be a listing of the good functions.

Define the function $h$ by $h(i)=0$ if $i$ is odd, and $h(2k)=1-f_k(2k)$. It is clear that $h$ is good. It is none of the $f_i$, since it differs from $f_k$ in the $2k$-th place.